# Random bit string of length k contains n "1" in a row

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I want to calculate how often on average you will find n "1" in a row in a randomly generated bit string of length k.

Ex:

```
bit string: 0011010110
k: 10
n: 2
result: 2
```

My approach:
is to calculate the number of bit strings which contains n "1" in a row and devide by all possible bit strings:

lets say
k = 5
n = 3

then you could have 12 possibilities

11100
11101
11110
11111

01110
01111
11110
11111

00111
01111
10111
11111

the number of possibilities is $(k-n+1)*2^{k-n}$

but I don't get rid of the duplicates 11111, 11110, 01111

Comment: Well... What efforts have you made in order to obtain that piece of knowledge?

Comment: you mean the example?

Comment: No, I mean, what have you tried yourself, in attempting to solve this problem on your own?

Comment: The number of bit strings of length $k$ that _don't_ contain $n$ ones in a row satisfies the recurrence $a_{k+1}=2a_k-a_{k-n}$ for $k>n$. Solving that analytically doesn't look promising for general $n$, but at least you can _calculate_ it using about $\log k$ matrix multiplications of size $(n+1)\times(n+1)$.

Comment: Your calculation is correct in the sense that the expected number of runs of length $n$ in a $k$-bit string is $$\frac{(k-n+1)*2^{k-n}}{2^k} = \frac{(k-n+1)}{2^n}.$$ But to be clear, you don't want the expected number of runs but rather the probability that a given string will contain *at least one* run?

Comment: I want the average number of runs in a bitstring of a given length